# Javascript get original browser width or resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

Can I get the original size of the browser even if it is minimized?

This code isn't working - perhaps it grabs the current size, not the original size.

```
var original_size = $(window).width();
var original_size2 = window.innerHeight;
var original_size3 = $(window).width() || window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: what do you mean by ***original size*** ?

Comment: Like the full screen size of the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're searching for:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

```js
console.log("Available Height: " + window.screen.availHeight);
console.log("Available Width: " + window.screen.availWidth);
```

Comment: I think you meant `window.screen.availHeight` in one of the first two lines. (availWidth is repeated twice).

Comment: @PedroLobito, You are a real genius, Thanks u saved me a lot of time and headache.